# Creating hierarchical combinations in Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, combinations, python-itertools

I have a interesting problem. I have a list with hierarchical data.

```
relation = [('grandfather'), ('father'), ('son')]
```

It is hierarchical in the sense that there can not be `son` without the `grandfather` but there can be `father` without `son`.

Each entry can have a status.

```
status = [('tall'), ('short')]
```

I am trying to find all possible combinations, that make sense. That is the combination

```
combination_sense = [('grandfather', 'tall'), ('father', 'short'), ('son', 'short')]
```

may exist, but the combination

```
combination_no_sense  = [('grandfather', 'tall'), ('son', 'short')]
```

may not exist, since  there cannot be `son` without `father`.

Likewise, the combiniation

```
combination_sense = [('grandfather', 'tall'), ('father', 'short')]
```

may indeed exist.

I tried myself out with `itertools`. I tried `list(itertools.product())` and `itertools.permutations()`, but I can't make it work sofar.

How do I take care of the hierarchical relationship?

Comment: Can you show us your actual data? Or at least a sample? And let me know when/if you've done so.

Comment: @BillBell I get the data exactly as shown, i.e. two simple lists. It’s botanical data showing father/child relations. The last entry on the list is always the youngest. The status is actually talk and short.

Comment: I understood 'It is hierarchical ...' to mean a number of possibilities: `[('grandfather'), ('father'), ('son')]` and  `[('grandfather'), ('father')]`.

Comment: Maybe I'm catching on. Generations must be contiguous: there must be an intervening generation (of course!). Two contiguous generations are allowed. Are single generations allowed? Each so-called 'status' can be applied to any of the generations in a list?

Comment: @BillBell exactly! Each generation may be short or tall. Single generations are allowed. Thank you for clarifying!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to produce all combinations of values from your two lists, but you're treating the lists differently than each other.

For the first, hierarchical list, you must always use the first value, and can extend the sequence of values by any amount as long as you don't skip any. So for your example list, you'd produce `['grandfather'], ['grandfather', 'father'], ['grandfather', 'father', 'son']`.

For the second list, you want all combinations (with replacement) that are the same length as the hierarchical value you're pairing them with.

This shouldn't be to hard to do with a custom generator function:

```
import itertools as it

def combine(relations, statuses):
    for i in range(len(relations)):
        relation = relations[:i+1]
        for status_combination in it.product(statuses, repeat=i+1):
            yield list(zip(relation, status_combination))
```

This starts with the smaller results first (e.g. those with only `'grandfather'`). If you wanted to start with the longest ones (the ones that include `'son'`), you can replace both instances of `i+1` in the code above with `len(relations)-i`.

If you want all contiguous subsequences of `relations` (so `['father', 'son']` would be allowed, as would both `['father']` and `['son']` by themselves), you can make just a few changes to get that result instead:

```
import itertools as it

def combine(relations, statuses):
    for start, stop in it.combinations(range(len(relations) + 1), 2): # get two indexes
        relation = relations[start:stop]                              # slice using both
        for status_combination in it.product(statuses, repeat=stop-start): # use difference
            yield list(zip(relation, status_combination))
```

Comment: Hi, great answer! One follow up question. How do I access the generator / covert it to a list?

Comment: EDIT: I mean as part of the function?

Comment: You can consume the generator by looping over it with a `for` statement (`for combination in combine(...):`) if you want to operate on each combination separately, or you can pass it to the `list` constructor (`results = list(combine(...))`) which will let you see all the combinations together.

Answer (score 1):

This version yields more contiguous generation possibilities, which is what I understood form our conversation. I don't know whether this is what you actually wanted or not.

```
from itertools import product

relations = ['grandfather', 'father', 'son']
statuses = ['tall', 'short']

possibilities = []
for per in range(1,4):
    contiguous_relations = [relations[i: i+per] for i in range(-per+1+len(relations))]
    possibilities.extend(contiguous_relations)

for possibility in possibilities:
    print('---', possibility)
    for p in product(statuses, repeat=len(possibility)):
        print (list(zip(possibility, p)))
```

Result:

```
--- ['grandfather']
[('grandfather', 'tall')]
[('grandfather', 'short')]
--- ['father']
[('father', 'tall')]
[('father', 'short')]
--- ['son']
[('son', 'tall')]
[('son', 'short')]
--- ['grandfather', 'father']
[('grandfather', 'tall'), ('father', 'tall')]
[('grandfather', 'tall'), ('father', 'short')]
[('grandfather', 'short'), ('father', 'tall')]
[('grandfather', 'short'), ('father', 'short')]
--- ['father', 'son']
[('father', 'tall'), ('son', 'tall')]
[('father', 'tall'), ('son', 'short')]
[('father', 'short'), ('son', 'tall')]
[('father', 'short'), ('son', 'short')]
--- ['grandfather', 'father', 'son']
[('grandfather', 'tall'), ('father', 'tall'), ('son', 'tall')]
[('grandfather', 'tall'), ('father', 'tall'), ('son', 'short')]
[('grandfather', 'tall'), ('father', 'short'), ('son', 'tall')]
[('grandfather', 'tall'), ('father', 'short'), ('son', 'short')]
[('grandfather', 'short'), ('father', 'tall'), ('son', 'tall')]
[('grandfather', 'short'), ('father', 'tall'), ('son', 'short')]
[('grandfather', 'short'), ('father', 'short'), ('son', 'tall')]
[('grandfather', 'short'), ('father', 'short'), ('son', 'short')]
```

Comment: Thank you a very much. This takes my question even further then I thought!

Comment: You're very welcome. Interesting question, and they don't appear often.